# Using sum() and count() for different columns in sql select statement

Tags: sql, count, group-by, subquery

I am still learning to write somewhat complex queries, so please excuse me if this sounds simple:

I have a table with the following data:

```
    Id        Service   Type      SubType    Status    Charge
------------------------------------------------------------------
    A         S1        Pr         100        Active     20
    A         S1        Pr         50         Active     10
    A         S2        Sec        20         Inactive   30
    A         S2        Sec        100        Inactive   50
    A         S2        Sec        50         Inactive   15 
    B         S3        Pr         100        Active     90
    B         S3        Pr         100        Active     40
```

Result:

```
Id   Active_Service  Inactive_Service  Total_Charge
----------------------------------------------------------
A         1               1                 20
B         1               0                 130
```

Where
`Total_Charge` is calculated when the `Service` for the `Id` is of `Type`: "Pr" and of `SubType`:100

I have written the query to display (Cust_id, Total_Charge) by grouping in one way (using `sum()` function). However, displaying the columns: (Active_Service, Inactive_Service) requires us to use grouping in another way (`count(1)`) in the same sql. How can we write one single query to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `max` to find if an `id` has any active service, and `sum` to add together values:

```
select  Id
,       max(case when status = 'Active' then 1 else 0 end) as Active_Service
,       max(case when status = 'Inactive' then 1 else 0 end) as Inactive_Service
,       sum(case when type = 'PR' and SubType = 100 then charge end) as Total_Charge
from    YourTable
group by 
        Id
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       sum(case when status = 'Active' then 1 else 0 end) as Active,
       sum(case when status = 'Inactive' then 1 else 0 end) as Inactive,
       sum(case when type = 'PR' and Subtype = 100 then charge end) as TotalCharge
from data d
group by id;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. But it seems it would give me Active_Service=2 (instead of 1) and Inactive_Service=3 (Instead of 1) for Id:A, and so on- which we don't intend here.